# Does anyone know why this array initialization statement won't work?

Tags: c

I am currently done this piece of code and I realized that my array initialization doesn't work when I give the size a variable containing a number and so on.. It only works when I put ana actual number in it. Why is that so?

For example:

Does not work:

```
unsigned int width = 5;
unsigned int height = 4;
const uint8_t img[width*height]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,6,2,1,1,2,5,3,8,6}; // why not?
```

Works:

```
unsigned int width = 5;
unsigned int height = 4;
const uint8_t img[20]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,6,2,1,1,2,5,3,8,6}; //manually placing 20
```

Should there be a reason why the first one doesn't work?

I plan on taking user input for the width and height so, the first one that should work but isn't working is really important for me.

Comment: you're aren't allowed to define variable length arrays like that in `c`.

Comment: How should I properly perform this if this is nota  valid operation?

Comment: I don't think my grading system will use that, so I guess I will need malloc for this?

Comment: If the sizes are always the same use the numbers or a `#define`. If they aren't always the same use a `malloc` call. `malloc` needs to be in a function and you'll have to fill it separately.

Comment: So I figured out how to use malloc, but how do I add numbers to it? Do I do img = "0,1,2,3...."? This is just manually adding for now, I plan to make it so that it stores values from user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use,

```
unsigned int width = 5;
unsigned int height = 4;
const uint8_t img[width*height] = {.......};
```

`img` is treated as a variable length array.

When you use

```
unsigned int width = 5;
unsigned int height = 4;
const uint8_t img[20] = {.......};
```

`img` is treated as array of known size.

The C99 Draft Standard (N1570) forbids initialization of variable length arrays.

> **6.7.9 Initialization**
>
> 2 The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or a complete
> object type that is not a variable length array type

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the initialization. You can't use variables to declare along with initialization parameters. Declare the array & initialize it in separate lines.

```
uint8_t img[width*height];
for(i=0;i<(width*height);i++)
    img[i]=?
```

You won't be able to make it const. Otherwise, omit the size:

```
const uint8_t img[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,7,9,6,2,1,1,2,5,3,8,6};
```

The array will automatically allocate the size according to the initial values.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I was negatived, I don't like that... I'm assuming it's because I'm wrong somewhere, probably on my exact understanding of C/C++ const usefulness in arrays.

Lemme try and be a bit more useful instead. If someone comments on this, please let me correct myself first. I remember it being possible to use **const** values in array initializations, but not non-const values, as they're considered variable arrays. It's possible to use variable arrays in C99, as long as the variable was passed as an argument and the array is initialized as just that value. I'd like clarification if I'm wrong.

The interesting thing I see is that there doesn't seem to be much purpose in using two variables, multiplying them together, and then setting those values to an array, unless the width and height values aren't known during compilation. If that were the case though, than an initializer would be inappropriate for an array. If they are, simply use an empty array initialization and let the compiler work it out.

Working:

```
const uint8_t img[] = {...};
```

Broken:

```
unsigned int someNum = 20;
const uint8_t img[someNum] = {...};
```

If you need a variable length array, just use `calloc()`.

```
unsigned int someNum = 20; // Or get this value from anywhere really.
uint8_t * const img = calloc(someNum, sizeof(unit8_t));
```

`calloc()` has the advantage of initializing all the values to 0 for you. If you don't want that, you can use `malloc()` instead. Take note of the location of the const in the second example, for if you make it **const uint8_t *** then the **values** in the array will be const, rather than the pointer to the array. If you want the array values to be const, just return the allocated array as a const uint8_t array. You'll need to clean up the array as well using this strategy.